# Matrix Slicing with Array in R

Tags: r, slice

Consider the following 2D array:

```
A = 
1 2 3 
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Given a set of indexes corresponding to the columns, for instance, i = [0, 2], I want to obtain a new matrix only with the 0th and 2nd column using R.

```
1 3
4 6
7 9
```

In Python, we can use the following line: A[:, i]. However, in R, I have no idea to do this. Could you provide me a solution?

Comment: In R you should use Use `A[, i]` where `i` starts from 1 and not 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R, the index of elements in data structures starts at 1

```
A <- matrix(data = 1:9,nrow = 3,byrow = TRUE)

A[,-2]
```

or

```
A[,c(1,3)]
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I want it specifically given a set of indexes.